# Doctrine - how to prevent cascade action in testing environment

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have this chunk of code :

```
class Event {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Supplier::class, inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL")
     **/
    private $supplier;
    ...
}
```

When an Event is deleted, the condition `cascade={"persist","remove"}` makes that the supplier is also deleted.

I would like to change this behavior **only for my testing environment**.

Is there a trick to do this ? if not, I will have to recreate the supplier each time an event is deleted....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a way to do what I want, but the only solution I had was to set the property `$supplier` to `null`  before deleting the event, so there's no cascade removing on any supplier.